# delete the marker along the circle around it

Tags: openstreetmap, leaflet

I am working with `Open Street Maps` and using `leaflet library`. 
I have a layer group like this:

```
var testLayer = new L.LayerGroup(); --> declared in a different file
```

I want to add markers to a marker group, add a circle around each marker, and add the marker group to the map:

[image]

```
var realMarker = L.marker([52.6432, -6.53412 ],{icon: Icon,title:data[choice][key]["name"]
                        }).bindPopup("Dublin").addTo(testLayer);
var circle = L.circle([52.6432, -6.53412 ],400, {
                        color: 'red',
                        fillColor: '#f03',
                        fillOpacity: 0.5
                    }).addTo(testLayer);

 map.addLayer(testLayer);
```

However, when I delete a particular marker from the marker group by using `removeLayer()`, the marker is removed from the map but the circle is left behind. How can I delete the circle along with the marker?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd store a reference to the circle in the marker:

```
var realMarker = L.marker([52.6432, -6.53412 ],
                          {icon: Icon,title:data[choice][key]["name"]}
                         ).bindPopup("Dublin").addTo(testLayer);
var circle = L.circle([52.6432, -6.53412 ],400, {
                        color: 'red',
                        fillColor: '#f03',
                        fillOpacity: 0.5
                    }).addTo(testLayer);
realMarker.circle=circle;
map.addLayer(testLayer);
```

Then, when removing the marker, also remove its circle

```
testLayer.removeLayer(markerToRemove);
testLayer.removeLayer(markerToRemove.circle);
```